# Pandas read_csv truncating 0s in zip code

Tags: python, pandas, geography

I am reading in a csv file of geographies. In the actual csv file, all zip codes are 5 digits. However, when I read it using pd.read_csv, all 0s are truncated from the zip code (00834 becomes 834).

I found a workaround (concatenate with '.' in excel on either side, then do some data manipulation in pandas) but I am still confused as to why read_csv truncated these values to begin with. I have tried reading it in as a string using the dtype argument in read_csv, and no change.

Why is it truncating values of the string '00834'?

Comment: define the dtype as string, you cannot have leading zeros with integers

Comment: I did that, it didn’t help